# FLTK - Can't find headers even if I include the correct directory

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, linker, fltk

I am trying to compile a FLTK project from linux, using the output of the commands:

> fltk-config --use-gl --use-images --ldflags

And:

> fltk-config --use-gl --use-images --cxxflags

I am using this makefile to compile the project:

[image]

I installed the latest FLTK version by just downloading it from fltk.org, and then I compiled and installed it. I also installed X11 and OpenGL. But I still get these errors:

[image]

I checked the file system and these headers are in /usr/local/include/FL even if they are not recognized, although I included the directory (-I/usr/local/include) and then in the .cpp and .h files:

```
#include <FL/Fl_PNG_Image.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
etc...
```

What could be the problem? do I need to install more libraries?

**EDIT**

I tried to change the makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -I/home/ramy/boost_1_63_0 -std=c++11

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lfltk_png -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk_gl -lGLU -lGL -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/home/ramy/boost_1_63_0/lib

SOURCES=Car.cpp Map.cpp CarState.cpp Utilities.cpp CarCollection.cpp TableView.cpp MapView.cpp
OBJECTS=Car.o Map.o CarState.o Utilities.o CarCollection.o TableView.o MapView.o

make:
    g++ $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES)
    g++ $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o ../Evolution table-example.cpp $(OBJECTS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) ../Evolution
```

But I still get the same errors.

Comment: I think you're definitely missing some of the -l flags.

Comment: @AlexanderLapenkov fltk-config should be give the right output. Could it be that I need to install more libraries other than FLTK and OpenGL? if I check in /usr/local/lib there are libfltk, libfltk_png, etc... but there are not libxext, libxcursor and many others.

Comment: Your errors are not compiler errors reporting missing headers. They are
linker errors reporting failures to find definitions for symbols that
are referenced in the linkage. They are caused because you are linking
all your libraries before all of the object files that refer to them.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I tried to compile the target in two steps (first objects, then the source containing the main), as you can see in my edit. But I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors don't mean that you are lacking headers, but libraries.

[Here](http://fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html) you can read the basis (go down to "Compiling Programs with Standard Compilers").
Basically add `-L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXext -lX11 -lm` to your app compiler command; or use `fltk-config --cxxflags`.

Comment: That's what I did. I'm already using the output of fltk-config.